# The finite groups with an irreducible faithful complex representation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

All the groups below are supposed finite, and their representations, complex.

An abelian group admits an irreducible faithful representation iff it is cyclic.
A group has all its non-trivial irreducible representations faithful iff it is simple.

*Question*: What's the classification of the groups admitting an irreducible faithful representation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question admits an answer in the following mathoverflow post:
[Which finite groups have faithful complex irreducible representations?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/57129/34538)